# Python - Using bs4 to parse specific data from html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am still new to python and learning as I go so please bear with me..
How does one get bs4 to get only the 'value= * number *' data from the code provided?

```
<div class="option-radios">
<label class="radio option-7">
    <em style="display: none"></em>

    <span class="radio-label">7</span>
    <input id="option-7"
            type="radio" name="option[1]"
            class=" property-uid1"
            value="59"              title="7" />
</label>

<label class="radio option-8">
    <em style="display: none"></em>

    <span class="radio-label">8</span>
    <input id="option-8"
            type="radio" name="option[1]"
            class=" property-uid1"
            value="61"              title="8" />
</label>

<label class="radio option-9">
    <em style="display: none"></em>

    <span class="radio-label">9</span>
    <input id="option-9"
            type="radio" name="option[1]"
            class=" property-uid1"
            value="62"              title="9" />
</label>

<label class="radio option-10">
    <em style="display: none"></em>

    <span class="radio-label">10</span>
    <input id="option-10"
            type="radio" name="option[1]"
            class=" property-uid1"
            value="63" checked="checked"                title="10" />
</label>

<label class="radio option-11">
    <em style="display: none"></em>

    <span class="radio-label">11</span>
    <input id="option-11"
            type="radio" name="option[1]"
            class=" property-uid1"
            value="60"              title="11" />
</label>
```

I can get all the data within the div but I am unable to narrow down the search to what I want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.session()
url = "url here"

a = session.get(url)

soup = bs(a.text,'html.parser')
sizes = soup.find('div',{'class':'option-radios'})
print(sizes)
```

Apologies again for likely a very basic question!

Comment: you will surely get an answer here, but it would be very beneficial for you if you had gone into bs4 docs and looked out for solutions by examples given there.

Comment: I have been reading so much over the last few days but perhaps I am burned out from information overload.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be better off with css selectors in this case:

```
for val in soup.select('label input'):
    print(val['value'])
```

Output (for the snippet in your question):

```
59
61
62
63
60
```